# SQL select from 1 x N where all bigger than

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have tables `books` and `bookType` which pose a 1 X n relationship.

`books`

```
+-----+------------------+----------+-------+
| id  |      title       | bookType | price |
+-----+------------------+----------+-------+
|   1 | Wizard of Oz     |        3 |    14 |
|   2 | Huckleberry Finn |        1 |    16 |
|   3 | Harry Potter     |        2 |    25 |
|   4 | Moby Dick        |        2 |    11 |
+-----+------------------+----------+-------+
```

`bookTypes`

```
+-----+----------+
| id  |   name   |
+-----+----------+
|   1 | Fiction  |
|   2 | Drama    |
|   3 | Children |
+-----+----------+
```

How would I retrieve bookTypes where all books are more expensive than e.g. 12($)?
In this case, the expected output would be:

```
+-----+----------+
| id  |   name   |
+-----+----------+
|   1 | Fiction  |
|   3 | Children |
+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from bookTypes t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from books b
    where b.bookType = t.id and b.price < 12
)
```

If you want to select book types that also have at least one associated book:

```
select t.*
from bookTypes t
where 
    exists (select 1 from books b where b.bookType = t.id)
    and not exists (select 1 from books b where b.bookType = t.id and b.price < 12)
```

Answer (score 4):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `HAVING` to return only booktypes having the lowest price > 12.

```
SELECT bt.name
FROM bookTypes bt
INNER JOIN books b ON b.bookType = bt.id
group by bt.name
HAVING SUM(b.price <= 12) = 0;
```

Comment: I think you need to count that the number of books with a price less than or equal to 12 is zero, i.e. they don't occur.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly consider using `having min(price) >= 12` with grouping by `bookType`

```
select t.id, t.name
  from bookTypes t
  join books b
    on t.id = b.bookType
 group by b.bookType   
 having min(price) >= 12
```

Moreover, if your DB's version is at least `10.2`, then you can also use some `window functions` for analytical queries such as `min(..) over (partition by .. order by ..)` :

```
with t as
(
select t.id, t.name, min(price) over (partition by bookType) as price
  from bookTypes t
  join books b
    on t.id = b.bookType
)
select id, name 
  from t
 where price >= 12
```

in which `min() over (..)` window function determines minimum price for each booktype by use of `partition by bookType`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=0c7f048df9441ced888d195aacf2dd84)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I think GMB's solution is likely the best so far. But for sake of completeness: You can also use the `ALL` operator with a correlated subquery. That's probably the most straight forward solution.

```
SELECT *
       FROM booktypes bt
       WHERE 12 < ALL (SELECT b.price
                              FROM books b
                              WHERE b.booktype = bt.id);
```

Comment: This is a nice solution too +1.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just select from books inner join bookTypes on id WHERE price > 12?

```
SELECT bt.*
FROM bookTypes bt
INNER JOIN books b ON b.bookType = bt.id
WHERE b.price > 12
```